# How to map Play/Pause key to mute/unmute Zoom?

Tags: keyboard, audio

I "converted" an old pair of headphones to wireless using a MPOW Wireless Receiver. Today I was on a Zoom call, muted and away from the keyboard and I wanted to unmute myself. So, I thought maybe the little play/pause button of the Wireless Receiver would do the trick but when I hit the button, the Music.app opened. After the call, I wondered if there was a way to map the play/pause to mute/unmute my mic in the Zoom.app?